# joining two tables with multiple conditions

Tags: postgresql, activerecord

I have following code in my template

```
<% @dishes.each do |d| %>
<div class="card">
    <img src="<%= d.image_url %>" alt="">
    <a href="/dishes/<%= d.id %>"><p><%= d.name %></p></a>
    <p><%= d.dish_type.name if d.dish_type %></p>
    <h4>@ <%= d.venue %></h4>

    <form action="/likes/<%= d.id %>" method="post">
        <button <%= 'disabled' if d.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id) %>>Like</button>
        <p>Count: <%= d.likes.count %></p>
    </form>
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on 'like' button I should disable the button.

I have three tables dishes, users, likes. likes table contains dish_id and user_id as foreign keys. You can say many to many relationship where likes is a junction table.

I am activerecord I have setup all the connections and belongs_to and has_many relations, they all are good.

The problem I am facing is at this particular line

```
<button <%= 'disabled' if d.likes.where(user_id:  current_user.id) %>>Like</button>
```

somehow the join condition is not working, it always evaluates to true. I tried different variations like using 'joins' and all but nothing is working.
Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if further information is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it always evaluates to true because the where clause is returning an active record relationship object.

If you want to get true or false from that particular query you can use "exist?":

```
 d.likes.exists?(user_id:  current_user.id)
```

If the record exists in the database you will get True otherwise False.